# Returns and qualified labels in Kotlin's Lambda functions

Tags: kotlin

I am struggling to understand a concept in kotlin.
Looking at [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-kotlin-lambda-expressions/)

```
val lambda = { greeting: String, name: String -> 
    if(greeting.length < 3) return // error: return not allowed here
    
    println("$greeting $name")
}
```

This would result in an error. Rewriting the lambda expression to this

```
val lambda = greet@ { greeting: String, name: String -> 
    if(greeting.length < 3) return@greet
    
    println("$greeting $name")
}
```

It works. And it works because "*... return from our lambda to the outer, calling function...*"

What I am struggling to understand is, what the *outer calling function* is. There is no other function, calling `lambda`. Whats going on under the hood here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that there is no other function calling `lambda` *right now*. What it means is that, when you do decide to call `lambda`, it will return to the function where you are doing that.

For example, if you have:

```
fun someFunction() {
    lambda()
    // some other code...
}
```

Then that `return@greet` will return to `someFunction`. `someFunction` is the "outer, calling function".

Just saying that might not be very meaningful, until you compare this to `return` without a label. Let's make up a situation where `return` and `return@label` are both allowed:

```
fun main() {
    aMoreMeaningfulExample foo@{
        if (it == 3) return@foo
        println(it)
    }
}

inline fun aMoreMeaningfulExample(lambda: (Int) -> Unit) {
    for (x in 1..5) {
        lambda(x)
    }
    println("Done!")
}
```

Here, `return@foo` returns to the "outer, calling function" of the lambda, which is `aMoreMeaningfulExample`. This means that `println(it)` will be skipped when `it` is 3. After returning to `aMoreMeaningfulExample`, the `for` loop there will still continue as normal, so you will see the rest of the numbers, and "Done!" being printed.

On the other hand, if you used `return`, it would return to whatever called `main`, in other words, terminating the program. You will only see "1" and "2" being printed.